Virtual Environment in Jupyter Notebook not switching project context
I attempted to setup a virtual environment in an OCI VM environment with Oracle 8 with Jupyter Notebook. After completing the configuration, the Notebook was able to pick the virtual environment name, but the installation still points to the default environment
I ran the following command at the terminal
python -m venv py39
source py39/bin/activate
pip install ipykernel
python -m ipykernel install --user --name-py39

Response
#Installed kernelspec py39 in /home/opc/.local/share/jupyter/kernels/py39

The configuration file at /home/opc/.local/share/jupyter/kernels/py39/kernel.json seems to be alright
{
 "argv": [
  "/home/opc/py39/bin/python",
  "-m",
  "ipykernel_launcher",
  "-f",
  "{connection_file}"
 ],
 "display_name": "py39",
 "language": "python",
 "metadata": {
  "debugger": true
 }
}

If I restart the jupyter notebook at the virtual environment the new environment is loaded and it becomes default too, I cannot switch to the previous environment on the Notebook terminal.
Is there a configuration file I need to edit to make the Jupyter Notebook switch context appropriately?
I do not have conda installed as I do not feel the need for it, is it the only way to go?
Thanks in advance

There's already a lot of posts on this topic on here. Edit your post to detail what have you tried in them that makes a new post necessary? And you shouldn't need conda because, as you think, it isn't the only way to go.

Related resources: here and here.
